How to select the embedded matrix in a unitary encoding?
I embed a matrix M in a U unitary, where $M$ is $2^n \times 2^n$, and $$U = \begin{bmatrix}M & *\\ * &*\end{bmatrix}$$ with twice as many rows and columns..
I prepare a state vector with the first qubit being $|0\rangle$, that is
$$ |0\rangle \otimes \underbrace{|v\rangle}_{n \text{ qubits}} = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\end{bmatrix}\otimes|v\rangle  = \begin{bmatrix}v \\ 0\end{bmatrix} \,.$$
The action of $U$ results in
$$ U \begin{bmatrix}v \\ 0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}M & *\\ * &*\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}v \\ 0\end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix}Mv \\ *\end{bmatrix}\,.$$
Now, I want to discard the $*$ part; in other words, I want to set the first qubit back to $|0\rangle$, so I have $$\begin{bmatrix}Mv \\ 0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} \otimes M|v\rangle = |0\rangle  \otimes M|v\rangle\,.$$(Scaling is omitted for brevity.)
The only way I can imagine doing this is to measure the first qubit and hope for $0$. So there must be another way to go about this, right?

What is the end goal of this circuit? Will you continue to evolve the state and will you need the first 0 qubit? Or are you putting the qubit simply to be able to implement $M$ as embedded into a Unitary matrix? I would like to help to the best of my ability if you could describe the context a bit more.

Thanks.This is just a step in the overall algorithm. I want to implement M as a subroutine.

As you know, a general resetting procedure can not be implemented unitarily. What blocks you from not operating on the first qubit again, and at the end, only take the results with first qubit $0$, as you've pointed out in your post? Is there a reason to search for another method.

@by24 I wish to apply more multiplications that are not unitary. If I need an extra qubit for every multiplication that would make the algorithm impractical.I was under the impression that applying a/some non-unitary operation (efficiently) has been worked out already and just wanted to understand the way it is done. Considering the lack of answers I conclude that this problem has not been solved yet. (Is it known to be not solvable?)

You say "scaling is omitted for brevity" but in fact this scaling is absolutely essential.
From a high-level perspective, you are asking to implement the map
$$|v\rangle \mapsto \frac{M|v\rangle}{\|M|v\rangle\|}.$$
If $M$ is not unitary, this map necessarily involves some $<1$ probability of preparation. This is achieved by the techniques of block encodings, qubitization, quantum signal processing, or the quantum singular value transformation more generally.
Let's write your block encoding with some appropriate normalization $\alpha \geq \|M\|$:
$$U = \begin{bmatrix}M/\alpha & *\\ * &*\end{bmatrix}.$$
Then the state you prepare is
$$|\psi\rangle = U|0\rangle |v\rangle = |0\rangle \frac{M}{\alpha}|v\rangle + |1\rangle |*\rangle.$$
Measuring the first qubit and observing $|0\rangle$ heralds the successful preparation of $\frac{M|v\rangle}{\|M|v\rangle\|}$ in the remaining register. This corresponds to measuring the POVM $\{E_i = |i\rangle\!\langle i| \otimes I : i = 0, 1\}$ and occurs with success probability
$$\Pr(E_0) = \mathrm{tr}(E_0 |\psi\rangle\!\langle \psi|) = \frac{\|M|v\rangle\|^2}{\alpha^2}.$$
The choice of $\alpha$ depends on the particular method used for constructing block encoding. If it is particularly large, this success probability will be small and so one would have to repeat many times to get a single success. One way to circumvent this is (oblivious) fixed-point amplitude amplification. The idea is to use Grover-like iterates to boost the amplitude of the $|0\rangle$ branch so that the probability of success is close to $1$. "Fixed-point" refers to a version of AA where, unlike Grover's classic algorithm which requires an exact # of iterates to get the maximum amplitude otherwise we "overcook" the quantum state, we can keep applying iterates and continue to improve our amplification. "Oblivious" refers to the fact that we don't need to know what $|v\rangle$ was in order to do this procedure. Note that this requires you to have access to both $U$ and $U^\dagger$. Roughly speaking, by querying $U$ and its inverse $O(\log(2/\delta)/\sqrt{\Pr(E_0)})$ times, the FPAA circuit produces a state  such that measuring the first qubit now prepares $\frac{M|v\rangle}{\|M|v\rangle\|}$ with probability no less than $1 -\delta^2$. Compared to just repeating until success, which needs ${\sim} 1/\Pr(E_0)$ repetitions (hence queries to $U$), this achieves the famous Grover quadratic speedup.
See the original paper here and a relevant follow-up here. Also see this useful tutorial and the seminal QSVT paper, which provides another strategy to boost the probability by "uniform singular value amplification" - essentially, uniformly boosting the norm of the block-encoded matrix from $M/\alpha$ to $M'/\alpha'$, where $M'$ is close to $M$ (with controllable error) and ideally $\alpha' \approx \|M\|$. The choice of FPAA vs. USVA will depend on your application and prior knowledge about $M$ and/or $|v\rangle$.

I really appreciate the response! Still working through it and the links before I can click the accept button. My background is math and I am still getting used to the notation.

I assume the dagger stands for complex conjugate which is also the ones of U. So what do you mean by having access to both? That seems to be automatic. Maybe you mean some kind of Oracle representation? In my case U is explicitly available.

So I understand that there is a probability of failure in applying the non unitary operator. I understand I can reduce this probability. However, in case of failure I need to repeat the process. This is impractical if you want many applications of a non unitary matrix. This does not take away from your answer, I just want to make sure I understand it correctly.

Yes, if you fail then you need to try again. Nonzero failure probability is inevitable for implementing a non-unitary transformation, as a necessary consequence of the postulates of quantum mechanics.

"Having access" just means the ability to implement, as a quantum operation/circuit/process, the map corresponding to $U$ or $U^\dagger$. The dagger refers to conjugate transpose, or the adjoint of a complex linear operator, which is the inverse when $U$ is unitary.
